# How to share RxJava Observable in parallel?

Tags: rx-java

In the sample code below, I'm trying to fetch from remote source1 and remote source2 - both of which requires input from remote source0. I would like to fetch from source0 only once AND fetch from source1 & source2 concurrently.

```
public class TestReactiveX5 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.io();
    RemoteSourceData<Integer, Integer> source0 = new RemoteSource0();
    RemoteSourceData<Integer, String> source1 = new RemoteSource1();
    RemoteSourceData<Integer, String> source2 = new RemoteSource2();

    Observable<Integer> i = Observable.just(1);
    Observable<Integer> i0 = i.map(input -> source0.getData(input)).share();
    Observable<String> fooSource = i0.map(input0 -> source1.getData(input0)).subscribeOn(scheduler);
    Observable<String> barSource = i0.map(input0 -> source2.getData(input0)).subscribeOn(scheduler);

    Observable<List<String>> merged = Observable.merge(fooSource, barSource).toList();
    merged.subscribe(val -> System.out.println(val));

    Thread.sleep(15000);
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  private static interface RemoteSourceData<IN, OUT> {
    public OUT getData(IN input);
  }

  public static class RemoteSource0 implements RemoteSourceData<Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer getData(Integer input) {
      try {
        System.out.println("fetch from remote Source0 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // ignore
      }
      return 0;
    }
  }

  private static class RemoteSource1 implements RemoteSourceData<Integer, String> {
    @Override
    public String getData(Integer i) {
      try {
        System.out.println("fetch from remote Source1 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Thread.sleep(4000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // ignore
      }
      return "foo";
    }
  }

  private static class RemoteSource2 implements RemoteSourceData<Integer, String> {
    @Override
    public String getData(Integer i) {
      try {
        System.out.println("fetch from remote Source2 " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Thread.sleep(4000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // ignore
      }
      return "bar";
    }
  }
}
```

The output for this shows that Source1 and Source2 aren't fetched in parallel:

```
fetch from remote Source0 2016-06-03 16:00:38.802
fetch from remote Source2 2016-06-03 16:00:40.803
fetch from remote Source1 2016-06-03 16:00:44.804
[bar, foo]
```

If I remove the share(), then Source1 and Source2 are fetched in parallel but requires two calls to Source0:

```
fetch from remote Source0 2016-06-03 16:05:48.027
fetch from remote Source0 2016-06-03 16:05:48.027
fetch from remote Source1 2016-06-03 16:05:50.028
fetch from remote Source2 2016-06-03 16:05:50.028
[foo, bar]
```

How can I get one call to Source0 and parallel calls to Source1 & Source2?

Comment: Use .cache() instead of .share().

Answer (score 0):

The sources are not being queried in parallel, because they use the same thread, which you put to sleep between the operations from different sources.

I added some additional logging to display executing threads for you basic example:

> fetch from remote Source0 2016-06-03 23:28:35.426 Thread=Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
>   fetch from remote Source1 2016-06-03 23:28:37.426 Thread=Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
>   fetch from remote Source2 2016-06-03 23:28:41.426 Thread=Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
>   [foo, bar]

As you can see, it's the same thread for all tasks that expectedly goes to sleep for 2s and 4s.

I tried different configurations of `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` and cannot say that it's totally transparent for me why RxJava does what it does in some cases, but here's something that worked for me:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.io();
  RemoteSourceData<Integer, Integer> source0 = new RemoteSource0();
  RemoteSourceData<Integer, String> source1 = new RemoteSource1();
  RemoteSourceData<Integer, String> source2 = new RemoteSource2();

  Observable<Integer> i = Observable.just(1).subscribeOn(scheduler);
  Observable<Integer> i0 = i.map(source0::getData).share();
  Observable<String> fooSource = i0.observeOn(scheduler).map(source1::getData);
  Observable<String> barSource = i0.observeOn(scheduler).map(source2::getData);

  Observable<List<String>> merged = Observable.merge(fooSource, barSource).toList();
  merged.subscribe(System.out::println);

  Thread.sleep(15000);
}
```

Output:

> fetch from remote Source0 2016-06-03 23:37:11.264 Thread=Thread[RxIoScheduler-3,5,main]
>   fetch from remote Source1 2016-06-03 23:37:13.265 Thread=Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
>   fetch from remote Source2 2016-06-03 23:37:13.265 Thread=Thread[RxIoScheduler-4,5,main]
>   [foo, bar]

Now `fooSource` and `barSource` have dedicated threads each and run in parallel.